# Conexion a base de datos remota

Tags: base-de-datos

Buenas, alguien sabe como ingresar a un servidor creado en wamp server en una red local desde otro equipo pero sin poner la ip?, 
me explico: para ingresar se tiene que poner la ip de la maquina en donde esta el servidor, yo necesito entrar sin poner la ip osea poniendo un nombre como si fuese un link.

Answer (score 0):

Para darle un nombre a una dirección IP configura el archivo `httpd.conf` en apache. Estará en el directorio:

```
c:\wamp\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf
```

Busca algo como:

```
DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www'
```

Y añade lo siguiente despues de DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www':

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www'
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot 'C:\wamp\www\ClientsMyClient'
</VirtualHost>
```

Te dejo el enlace de stack inglés: [Wamp con nombre de dominio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529006/wamp-in-network-with-a-domain-name)

**EDITO según comentarios:**

Para que tu servidor tenga siempre la misma IP, y los clientes puedan conectarse siempre sobre la misma IP, tienes que evitar que a tu servidor se le asigne una IP aleatoria mediante DHCP.

Para ello, sólo tienes que asignarle una IP fija al ordenador en el que esté el servidor. Esto se hace en la configuración ipv4.

Redes e internet > Cambiar la configuración del adaptador > Conexión de area local > Propiedades > Protocolo de internet versión 4 (ipv4) > Propiedades > Y ahí indicas la IP que quieras. [IP Fija](https://www.redeszone.net/windows/ip-privada-fija-en-windows-7/)

De este modo el servidor siempre mantendrá la misma IP.

Comment: esto es para poner online una web cieto?

Comment: No, sólo para que puedas acceder a tu web local mediante un nombre, en vez de mediante la IP

Comment: pero si lo que quiero es conectar un programa de escritorio a una base de datos que esta en otro equipo? serviria?

Comment: Ahora mismo cómo accedes?

Comment: Ahora mientras desarollo accedo mediante la ip, pero cuando cree el instalador del programa, el ingreso por ip no va a funcionar

Comment: Por qué no va a funcionar?

Comment: Porque mientras lo estoy desarrollando puedo cambiar la ip en la linea de conexión para conectarme, pero un vez echo el instalador eso ya no podrá cambiarse, y al instalar el programa en otro equipo la ip va a cambiar y el programa se caerá.

Comment: No veo por qué la IP iba a cambiar. Te refieres a que el ordenador coge una IP diferente cada vez que lo enciendes? (DHCP). Porque el darle un nombre a una IP no te va a solucionar ese problema, ya que el nombre va asociado a una IP, y si cambia, el nombre no va a llevarte a la IP buena.

Comment: Exacto, al cambiar de equipo la ip cambia y no encuentro manera de que la  el código de conexión del programa coincida con la ip del equipo donde esta el servidor se entiende?

Comment: El servidor siempre está en el mismo equipo no?

Comment: técnicamente si, aunque cuando entregue el proyecto si lo instalan en otro equipo no creo que funcione.
Dices que antes de generar el instalador debo configurar la ip del equipo del servidor

Comment: Edito la respuesta con lo que necesitas ahora mismo. En el caso de la entrega del proyecto, imagino que el servidor y el cliente serán el mismo PC, por lo que accederán mediante localhost. Pero no creo que sea un problema, ya que cada uno tendrá la instalación de wamp a su manera y puede diferir el directorio. PD: Igual deberías trabajar sobre el mismo ordenador, para acceder siempre mediante localhost.

Comment: Lo ultimo. en el caso de que quiera dejarlo ya instalado para su uso, primero se debe configurar la ip del servidor y luego ponerla en el codigo del programa y con eso ya queda funcionando, se hace asi o de otra forma?
desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Exacto así estaría bien. Aunque si tanto el servidor y el cliente son el mismo ordenador, no haría falta. Simplemente usar `localhost` como dirección.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar poner IP, yo uso el programa DUC de [NO-IP](https://www.noip.com/), es gratuito. Funciona de la siguiente manera:

1.- Te registras y bajas el programa (DUC) a tu servidor.

2.- En el sitio o en la misma aplicación, crea un dominio que servirá de alias para reconocer ese servidor en la red.

2.1.- [Adicional] Configura tu router para que todas las conexiones lleguen directamente al servidor.

3.- Cambia tu conexión con el número IP por el dominio (alias) que generaste.

Esto te permitirá conectarte a tu servidor desde cualquier lugar.

Saludos.